# Why does the Linux C API 'open' support function overloading?

Tags: c, linux, api, overloading

According to [the Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), the Linux C API `open` has two prototypes as follows:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int oflags);
int open(const char *pathname, int oflags, mode_t mode);
```

What makes me confused is:

**Why does the Linux C API 'open' support function overloading??**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, C doesn't support function overloading.

The POSIX [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) function is actually a variadic function, its signature is:

```
int open(const char *path, int oflag, ... );
```